# Have something done or have done something

Tags: grammar, tense

Think of this situation:
You are really bored and suddenly say to your friend:

> At least let's tickle ourselves so that we have done something
>   Or
>   At least let's tickle ourselves so that we have something done.

> At least let's tickle ourselves to have something done.
>   Or
>   At least let's tickle ourselves to have done something.

I'm trying to make a connection between these kinds of sentences and a tense in my language.

There are so many examples like this:

It's holiday. Everybody has gone to somewhere outside the town (maybe near the lake) but you and your friends are in the house. You say:

> let's go to the roof and pretend(suppose) that we have gone somewhere
>
> Shorter form??
>
> let's go to the roof so that we have gone somewhere (at least) or (so far).

Comment: I understand the context, but I don't understand what you are trying to say in the response. "let's tickle ourselves" is OK as it resolves being bored, but the rest of the phrase is unclear. You should add specific wording rather than "something done" which could mean many, many things.

Comment: @user3169 POST EDITED

Answer (score 2):

In the example given, it should be

> At least let's tickle ourselves so that we **have done something**.

"We have done something" is a past tense of "we do something".

---

To "have something done" has a couple of meanings:

- To have something done (by another person)

  Example: "*I'm having my car washed today.*"
- To have something (that is) done

  Example: "*Now that I have my chores finished, I can go out for the evening.*"

Answer (score 0):

It can only be 
--> *"At least let's tickle ourselves so that we **have done** something."*

**have + object + past participle** means that somebody else did something for you, like in the example *"I have my hair cut".* The have-part in this sense carries the tense and could therefore also be *"have had"* or *"will have",* like in _"I have had my hair cut" or *"I will have my hair cut"*

while

**have + past participle** is a tense (--> **present perfect**) as is the first sentence in your example which should be the appropriate choice here.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score -2):

As far As I I have read, **have something done** pattern is causative use. So,you would need to re-write them as follows:

> At least let's tickle it ourselves so that we can have done something done.

Here, I have used 'can' to show the ability in having something done.It's common to use model verb 'can' after the conjunction 'so that'.
It would be better if you could provide the context of this sentence. This sentence doesn't make much sense in itself without right context.